# How to detect UITextField cursor move without typing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

When a user only moves the cursor without typing a new word (i.e. `(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange) replacementString:(NSString *)string` does not get triggered), how do I detect this event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `selectedTextRange` property observer in viewDidAppear,

```
[self.txtfield addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedTextRange" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld  context:nil];
```

Then add function for this property,

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectedTextRange"] && self.txtfield == object)
        NSLog(@"cursor moved");
}
```

When you move the cursor without typing any text it should print "cursor moved".

Answer (score 1):

There is a [selectedTextRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614541-selectedtextrange) property in `UITextField` adopted from `UITextInput` protocol. So you can either subscribe to changes of this property with KVO or implement your own subclass with the method `setSelectedTextRange` overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure too sure that is any native delegate of UITextField for cursor movements  but you can subclass UITextField and can override method

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {

        let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)

        print("\(cursorPosition)")
    }
}
```

and whenever cursor moves then it should be  can check get cursor location.